# SignedData / DigestAlgorithm and SignedData / SignerInfo / DigestAlgorithm: same?

Tags: digital-signature, pkcs#7

[RFC 6488](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6488.txt) specifies the following content of `Signed-Data` content type:

```
  SignedData ::= SEQUENCE {
    version CMSVersion,
    digestAlgorithms DigestAlgorithmIdentifiers,
    encapContentInfo EncapsulatedContentInfo,
    certificates [0] IMPLICIT CertificateSet OPTIONAL,
    crls [1] IMPLICIT RevocationInfoChoices OPTIONAL,
    signerInfos SignerInfos }
```

The text explains:

```
The digestAlgorithms set contains the OIDs of the digest algorithm(s)
used in signing the encapsulated content.  This set MUST contain
exactly one digest algorithm OID [...]
```

Then, inside `SignerInfo`, there is another `DigestAlgorithmIdentifier`:

```
 SignerInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    version CMSVersion,
    sid SignerIdentifier,
    digestAlgorithm DigestAlgorithmIdentifier,
    signedAttrs [0] IMPLICIT SignedAttributes OPTIONAL,
    signatureAlgorithm SignatureAlgorithmIdentifier,
    signature SignatureValue,
    unsignedAttrs [1] IMPLICIT UnsignedAttributes OPTIONAL }
```

And the explanation is:

```
The digestAlgorithm MUST consist of the OID of a digest algorithm
that conforms to the RPKI Algorithms and Key Size Profile
specification [RFC6485].
```

In a couple of PKCS#7 files I peeked in, these two elements had equal value.

Is this a duplication of the same attribute? If not, what is the meaning of either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a duplication of the same attribute? If not, what is the meaning of either?

In case of RPKI yes.

The reason is that this standard does not introduce a specialized new structure but merely a profile of an existing one:

> > The RPKI signed object is a profile of the CMS [RFC5652] signed-data object

A CMS signed-data object in contrast to your RPKI one may contain multiple **SignerInfo** object in its **signerInfos** set, and each of them might make use of a different **digestAlgorithm**. Thus, in a CMS signed-data object the initial **digestAlgorithms** set may sensibly contain multiple entries.

Actually that field is even more liberally specified:

> > digestAlgorithms is a collection of message digest algorithm
> >           identifiers.  There MAY be any number of elements in the
> >           collection, including zero.  Each element identifies the message
> >           digest algorithm, along with any associated parameters, used by
> >           one or more signer.  The collection is intended to list the
> >           message digest algorithms employed by all of the signers, in any
> >           order, to facilitate one-pass signature verification.